# Why is SSL support for Nextcloud reccomended to be realized by means of a reverse proxy?

Tags: ssl, docker, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

In the readme of the official docker image for nextcloud it is stated, that it is recommended to use the image behind a reverse proxy that provides SSL ([Source](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker#https---ssl-encryption)). While its obvious, that a installation exposed to the internet needs encrypted connections, this particular method of implementation strikes me (as a web development n00b) as odd.

Why is a reverse proxy recommended as opposed to configuring the web server in the docker image such, that only ssl connections are accepted?
Isn't it rather inefficient to run a second, full-featured web server for ssl only?

Comment: While a reverse proxy doesn't mean a "full-featured" web server, I suspect this is more of Docker Way Of Doing Things than anything Nextcloud-specific?

Comment: @user1686 You're right regarding the reverse proxy. I was thinking of an example configuration where nginx was used as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user1686 says, this is the "Docker way": each container does one thing and does it well (separation of concerns). Using distinct containers, you also  reduce the need to tinker with provided images, and avoid having to deal with diverging software dependencies.

The other benefit is is that you have more freedom to decide what runs where. Light loads can run in a single server, but as load increases, you may find useful to run several instances of the Nextcloud container (the reverse proxy also acting as a load-balancer), initially on the same server, and later on distinct servers to increase I/O bandwidth.

A possible side benefit is that in case of a  Nextcloud vulnerability, the attcker can be restricted to the Nextcloud container and won't be able to hack the front-end.

Also, note that even without Docker, it is a fairly standard procedure to have an Apache/Nginx front-end (that will do the SSL termination among other things) to application servers (Tomcat, Springboot, or else).